# Javascript Cookies undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to save a value for a number in a cookie

```
var num = 1;
```

I used these 2 functions to set a cookie and read it

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
};
```

and

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
        var x = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        console.info("Value of num = " +x);
    }
};
```

I call the function like this

```
cname = "cookie1";
createCookie(cname,num,0);
readCookie(cname);
```

In the console I get that the cookie is undefined or something like "5_655666=xKV1REGZllELnKC1ZJQ7BAlbbFYAAAAA4wCdPor9VSiD08vABGt6oA=="
"cookie1 gers=false"
"cookie1 nds=false"
many times I cant figure out what is the problem.

Comment: And his name is John Cena! http://www.myinstants.com/instant/and-his-name-is-john-cenaaaaaa/ (sorry I couldn't resist).

Comment: When I run this code I get `Value of num = 1`, that seems correct. Does the code maybe fail on particular content of the cookie?

Comment: Can you show us the value of `document.cookie`?

Comment: I went thru the code again I guess i had a mistake somewhere but now it works :D Thanks anyway for trying to help and running the code to check if  it works! <3